# SQL Server database recovery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I simply copied my .mdf/.ldf files to another file and suddenly my Microsoft SQL 2008 database dies. I can't open these files on another system either. Can anyone explain what's happened? Any way to recover this application's database now?

Comment: What do you mean "another file"?

Comment: Please don't do this. File manipulations against SQL Server files will wreak havoc in SQL Server.  That being said, canyou let us know what errors SQL Server is throwing in the event viewer?

Answer (score 3):

Did you stop the service or detach the files first?

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to copy files when the server is online.

if you want to copy when the server is online, you can right click on management studio , -> detach->

then copy the files to another instance , and  choose attach on new server. remember you need to know the location of the files, before  you detach, also you should be knowing, also the logins need to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the database files back to where they were? (Specifically, stop SQL server, move files, start SQL Server).

Whenever I do this kind of work, I make copies of the files, and rename the original ones (from, say, MyData.mdf to xMyData.mdf). Makes it easier to back out when my fatfingers take over.